# Preloader not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I add the following script in a jsp page:

```html
<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/loadingoverlay.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.LoadingOverlay("show");
        //$.LoadingOverlay("hide");

        setTimeout(function(){
            $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

THE ISSUES:
it is working with `setTimeout(function()`
but not working with loading.

even the timeout function working after loading the page!

Requesting help for the solution - working the preloader while loading and disappear once complected

Comment: try it without the document ready function

Comment: add ur preload html in question pls

Comment: @madalinivascu, _Why ?_  As per docs, _Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute._

Comment: @OP, Use `$(window).load(handler)` to hide the loader..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// code
};
```

loads the de code when the rest of the document is loaded.
when you should load the script before the documents load with:

```
$(window).load(function() {
// code
});
```